# distribute work on multiple servers to increase throughput

Tags: java

I have multiple files that need processing(using java), I want to distribute these files among servers to speed up the operation instead of using multi-threaded application on the same server, and to have the ability to increase the performance with adding new server, what technologies should I look into? RMI? Hadoop ?

Comment: Is it real-time or offline processing?

Answer (score 0):

If this is justified by the complexity of processing and the amount of data you could have a look at data grid solutions like [hazelcast](http://hazelcast.com/) or similar products.

There are lots of alternatives, so if you want a thorough assessment of your needs you should be more specific about what your processing will look like,

Comment: I have large number of pdf files which I need to compare or might extract data from etc...

Comment: From what I read about hazelcast this can be a good solution for your needs. Perhaps it is a good idea to head for the hazelcast community, describe your demand there and ask for their opinion. As far as I know the community there it more happily accepts "debates" than stackoverflow does ;-)

Comment: @fadytaher If you need to rely on single processing of PDF files Hazelcast might not be the best solutions as Hazelcast does not guarantee exactly-once with queues. We replaced Hazelcast therefore with a JMS (ActiveMQ in our case)